# How to map one POJO to another POJO in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, annotations

Map User table to UserProfilePersonalInfo table for update the data

In User POJO map

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "users",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private UserProfilePersonalInfo userProfilePersonalInfo;
```

In UserProfilePersonalInfo POJO

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

In Hibernate configuration

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new  
    LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.a2z.model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect",  
    environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
    environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", 
    environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;        
}
```

I am facing error on console

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersService': Error creating bean with name 'usersService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userdao': Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userdao': Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users
Sep 30, 2016 7:32:38 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersService': Error creating bean with name 'usersService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userdao': Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userdao': Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/a2z/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.a2z.model.User.userProfilePersonalInfo, referenced property unknown: com.a2z.model.UserProfilePersonalInfo.users
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mappedBy = "user"
```

Here is the java field name, not the sgbd field name. Tips: Use sgbd field name where the word Column appear in the @annotation